# Why does a no-op filter-branch create divergence, and how do I fix that?

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

I have a situation where I merged a couple-years-worth of commits into a repository.  One of the commits had a comment which was a paste of an Address Sanitizer log related to the fix.

That doesn't sound so bad, except address Sanitizer logs look like this:

```
==10856==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address
0x62a00000b201 at pc 0x47df61 bp 0x7fffffff2ca0 sp 0x7fffffff2c98
READ of size 1 at 0x62a00000b201 thread T0
#0 0x47df60 in Expand_Series ../src/core/m-series.c:145
#1 0x47e5a7 in Extend_Series ../src/core/m-series.c:187
#2 0x466e0c in Scan_Quote ../src/core/l-scan.c:462
#3 0x46a797 in Scan_Token ../src/core/l-scan.c:918
#4 0x46e263 in Scan_Block ../src/core/l-scan.c:1188
...
```

And on it goes up to #250 or so in this case.  GitHub scans for #XXX patterns and if they match an issue number, put a note about the mention on the referenced issue.  So suddenly GitHub thinks this commit is remarking on every issue and pull request, and will be doing so for some time.

I thought I'd just use a `git filter-branch` as I don't really mind breaking from the history *(I had to do a filter-branch already to get rid of some stuff I didn't want)*.  However, I did that other filter-branch before I did a merge and continued with work.  Now that I've noticed this popping up in GitHub, I'd like to go back and rewrite it and don't mind if every commit on every branch *after* this point gets a new hash.  That's okay with me.

The rewrite I got to work, but what I can't figure out is why there is so much divergence.  It seems to have done rewriting that's affecting things before I made any changes to the comment.  As a simple test, I tried what I thought should be a no-op:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed "s/a/a/g"' -- --all
```

I'm no sed person, but my understanding is that would redo all the commit messages and substitute `a` with `a`.  *(Ayn Rand would be pleased.)*

It doesn't diverge as many commits as my actual replacement... 600 instead of 1000.  But that it diverges at all indicates I have some kind of misunderstanding here.  How can I rewrite [that commit message in the history](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c/commit/84c101d22399b03586fbbc8296043155d4f04a6d) without damaging any commits besides ones that occur after it...and get the effect on all branches?

Comment: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#examples with `--replace-text` for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra place that might be the culprit *(and was in my case)*.  Consider:

```
$ git cat-file -p 20b9cd59c6c6a1a2bccfb2ddb9af68c083a28698
tree dee80bcd856b23aceb8946473bf64d9aef0fe629
parent b12dc8b9388dc0a2ae34563426043a612d296195
author XXX <xxx@example.com> 1355477802 +0200
committer XXX <xxx@example.com> 1355478447 +0200
encoding cp1251

Add (literally) three characters to one file that will
inadvertently create hours of fun for people years later.
```

It's the encoding, in this case [Windows 1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251).
The person who found it summarized it thusly:

> msg-filter gets the raw message, no encoding meta-information.
>   So even when you use an 8-bit transparent msg-filter (such as a
>   plain cat), the re-created commit won't contain that encoding
>   meta-information.
>
> (That's slightly imprecise, because the filter gets the encoding
>   information, it could read it via the GIT_COMMIT env variable.
>   It's the output, that doesn't control encoding. At least I don't
>   know how...)

He fixed the general mess in our particular situation using [Graft Points](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint).  That is beyond my current git knowledge, so I will not attempt to explain it.

Comment: Wow, ouch.  The commit got modified by dropping the encoding.  This seems like a filter-branch bug of sorts, not that it can supply as much help as one would like but it could at least extract the message encoding and put in in an env variable so that an 8-bit clean filter preserves it!

Comment: @torek Pretty sneaky.  I wonder if there's a good way to prevent such encodings from slipping in?  Accepting this since it was the problem in my case, but thanks again for your thorough answer...

Answer (score 4):

If there is an existing message that does *not* end with a newline, `sed` will add one (at least some versions of sed, including the one I tested here):

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar'
foo
bar$ printf 'foo\nbar' | sed 's/a/a/'
foo
bar
$
```

which means your test message filter might have altered a message.  Based on your results, I'd guess that at least one commit, about 600 commits back from some branch tip(s), was modified this way.  (I've seen this exact problem myself before.)

(Another possibility is some sort of Unicode normalization, although I haven't seen that happen with `sed`.)

Assuming this is the case, the trick for you will be to find a command that does not affect other commits.  One good one is to use the environment variable `$GIT_COMMIT` to identify the commit(s) to touch, and make sure you do something that's truly a no-op (a `cat` msg-filter might work better than `sed`, for instance) on all other commits:

```
... --msg-filter 'if [ $GIT_COMMIT == <the one> ]; then fix_msg; else cat; fi' ...
```

As for getting the effect on all branches, your `-- --all` *should* do the trick already.

---

It sounds like you already know why the remaining commits get new SHA-1s but just for completeness I will include this as well.  You can skip this part, it's here for other people reading the question.

If a commit is modified, it gets a new SHA-1 (by definition, since the SHA-1 is the checksum of the commit's contents).  No big deal so far, but let's say that there are just five commits (all on master in this case, not that it matters) and we will modify the middle one with a filter-branch filter:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E        [original]
```

Let's say the actual SHA-1 for `C` starts with `30001`).  Now let's build a partial result, in the middle of the filter-branch operation:

```
A <- B <- C'
```

Let's say, by some weird coincidence, the new SHA-1 starts with `30002`, Version 2 of Commit 3.

Let's take a look at (part of) original commit `D`:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD^
tree 954019cba5244a4a135ff62258660b3d2e3a8087
parent 30001...
```

Commit `D` refers, by number, to commit `C`.  So `filter-branch`, while it changes nothing *else* about `D`, must construct a new commit `D'` that says `parent 30002...`:

```
A <- B <- C' <- D'
```

Likewise, `filter-branch` is forced to copy old commit `E` to new `E'`:

```
A <- B <- C' <- D' <- E'     [replacement]
```

Hence any `filter-branch` that changes some commit, also changes all subsequent commits.  (This is true for `git rebase` as well.  In fact, `git rebase` and `git filter-branch` are kind of cousins.  Both simply read existing commits, apply some change(s), and write the results as new commits; filter-branch does it all programmatically—i.e., has no `--interactive` mode—and has a very wide and complex set of specifications to make changes, and can then apply it to multiple branches, instead of one single branch.)

Comment: Great information, thanks!  Even the stuff I knew, for search posterity...good form (there's going to be orders of magnitude more of them than there are of me).  :-)  It sounds like you're almost certainly correct...and I wanted to get to this today, but it's looking like I might not be able to.  I will report back when I do...

Comment: Well, when getting back to this it turned out to be a bit trickier with [character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31601082/211160)...!  Don't know how long it would have taken me to find that on my own.  :-/